# MySQL query column using query stored in column (what?)

Tags: mysql, sql

We have some_table with the following columns:

```
ID, Title, `SQL`
```

The `SQL` column stores the query needed to create a list of ID's from another_table:

```
select ID from another_table where Foo = 'Bar'...
```

I wish to list all the rows in some_table with a count of the `SQL` result array from the `SQL` itself:

```
select ID, Title, count(`SQL`) from some_table...
```

So each row result would look like this:

```
ID | Title | Count
1  | Cows  | 1,232
2  | Sheep | 253
```

etc...

Comment: You need to do this using dynamic SQL -- with `prepare` and `exec`.

Comment: Is this the only way? I use the count(`SQL`) in results from other queries using other tables. Just having trouble using the `SQL` on the table itself. Tried `@sql:=SQL, count(@sql)` with no success.